# Make gmail and facebook login buttons inline

Tags: css

I have 2 buttons

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

They are generating respective buttons on the html page like this

[image]

I want them to be inline and at the center of page. The live URL of the page is

> http://apptellect.cloudapp.net/binance/login

If I use my custom buttons, the functions do not work so I can not use my own custom buttons or icons. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try `.g-signin2 {
    display:  inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use       `display:flex;` and
      `justify-content: center;`

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.fb_iframe_widget{ padding-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<fb:login-button size="medium" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" login_text="" class="fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=288951165192480&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;scope=public_profile%2Cemail&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=medium"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 64px; height: 22px;"><iframe name="ff0439d3632534" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=288951165192480&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2F3tXFuAe2xUh.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df383b64291c2b1%26domain%3Dapptellect.cloudapp.net%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapptellect.cloudapp.net%252Ff2d1ca372cb0084%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;scope=public_profile%2Cemail&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=medium" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 64px; height: 22px;" class=""></iframe></span></fb:login-button>
                <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-gapiscan="true" data-onload="true"><div style="height:36px;width:120px;" class="abcRioButton abcRioButtonLightBlue"><div class="abcRioButtonContentWrapper"><div class="abcRioButtonIcon" style="padding:8px"><div style="width:18px;height:18px;" class="abcRioButtonSvgImageWithFallback abcRioButtonIconImage abcRioButtonIconImage18"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" class="abcRioButtonSvg"><g><path fill="#EA4335" d="M24 9.5c3.54 0 6.71 1.22 9.21 3.6l6.85-6.85C35.9 2.38 30.47 0 24 0 14.62 0 6.51 5.38 2.56 13.22l7.98 6.19C12.43 13.72 17.74 9.5 24 9.5z"></path><path fill="#4285F4" d="M46.98 24.55c0-1.57-.15-3.09-.38-4.55H24v9.02h12.94c-.58 2.96-2.26 5.48-4.78 7.18l7.73 6c4.51-4.18 7.09-10.36 7.09-17.65z"></path><path fill="#FBBC05" d="M10.53 28.59c-.48-1.45-.76-2.99-.76-4.59s.27-3.14.76-4.59l-7.98-6.19C.92 16.46 0 20.12 0 24c0 3.88.92 7.54 2.56 10.78l7.97-6.19z"></path><path fill="#34A853" d="M24 48c6.48 0 11.93-2.13 15.89-5.81l-7.73-6c-2.15 1.45-4.92 2.3-8.16 2.3-6.26 0-11.57-4.22-13.47-9.91l-7.98 6.19C6.51 42.62 14.62 48 24 48z"></path><path fill="none" d="M0 0h48v48H0z"></path></g></svg></div></div><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:34px;" class="abcRioButtonContents"></span></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. can i resize them to same height and width? A little space between them would be perfect too.

Comment: And what about the height and width?

Comment: change this line to this:`<div style="height:36px;width: 64px;" class="abcRioButton abcRioButtonLightBlue">`

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I think you want like this:-

```css
.btnParent{ text-align:center;}
.btnParent .btnClass{ display:inline;}
.btnParent .btnClass .g-signin2{ display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="btnParent">
<div class="btnClass"><fb:login-button size="medium" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">btn1
</fb:login-button></div>

<div class="btnClass"><div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">btn2</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First **style** them **so** they **both** would be **the same size**. Then **put them in** a **div** with **style** of **`display: inline`** should work I think. From there you can just style them separately so one float there or other one there, off page is the limit!

Answer (score 0):

just do this, make a container and put both element into container like this :

```css
.btnsarea{display:flex;}
.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto 3px auto auto;
}

.g-signin2 {
    margin: auto auto auto 0;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnsarea"><fb:login-button size="medium" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" login_text="
                        " class=" fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=288951165192480&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;scope=public_profile%2Cemail&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=medium"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 64px; height: 22px;"><iframe name="f22512bd6207a88" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://web.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=288951165192480&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2F3tXFuAe2xUh.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df18fa6e2d2f4cd8%26domain%3Dapptellect.cloudapp.net%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapptellect.cloudapp.net%252Ff1a232b0e5afa74%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;scope=public_profile%2Cemail&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=medium" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 64px; height: 22px;" class=""></iframe></span></fb:login-button><div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-gapiscan="true" data-onload="true"><div style="height:36px;width:120px;" class="abcRioButton abcRioButtonLightBlue"><div class="abcRioButtonContentWrapper"><div class="abcRioButtonIcon" style="padding:8px"><div style="width:18px;height:18px;" class="abcRioButtonSvgImageWithFallback abcRioButtonIconImage abcRioButtonIconImage18"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" class="abcRioButtonSvg"><g><path fill="#EA4335" d="M24 9.5c3.54 0 6.71 1.22 9.21 3.6l6.85-6.85C35.9 2.38 30.47 0 24 0 14.62 0 6.51 5.38 2.56 13.22l7.98 6.19C12.43 13.72 17.74 9.5 24 9.5z"></path><path fill="#4285F4" d="M46.98 24.55c0-1.57-.15-3.09-.38-4.55H24v9.02h12.94c-.58 2.96-2.26 5.48-4.78 7.18l7.73 6c4.51-4.18 7.09-10.36 7.09-17.65z"></path><path fill="#FBBC05" d="M10.53 28.59c-.48-1.45-.76-2.99-.76-4.59s.27-3.14.76-4.59l-7.98-6.19C.92 16.46 0 20.12 0 24c0 3.88.92 7.54 2.56 10.78l7.97-6.19z"></path><path fill="#34A853" d="M24 48c6.48 0 11.93-2.13 15.89-5.81l-7.73-6c-2.15 1.45-4.92 2.3-8.16 2.3-6.26 0-11.57-4.22-13.47-9.91l-7.98 6.19C6.51 42.62 14.62 48 24 48z"></path><path fill="none" d="M0 0h48v48H0z"></path></g></svg></div></div><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:34px;" class="abcRioButtonContents"><span id="not_signed_inycu4sjx2rmus">Sign in</span><span id="connectedycu4sjx2rmus" style="display:none">Signed in</span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

dont forget to set these on less than or equal to 990px width

you can use it by copy pasting

view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suyvm.png

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```css
.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.loginBtn--facebook {
  background-color: #4C69BA;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4C69BA, #3B55A0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354C8C;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:before {
  border-right: #364e92 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_facebook.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:hover,
.loginBtn--facebook:focus {
  background-color: #5B7BD5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5B7BD5, #4864B1);
}

.loginBtn--google {
  background: #DD4B39;
}
.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_google.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}
```

```html
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">
  Login with Facebook
</button>

<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">
  Login with Google
</button>
```